# Suppress autocorrect on HTML input Safari iOS

Tags: ios, safari, html-input, autocorrect

I have this search input but no matter which of these attributes I add, or whether it's `off` or `false` I still get the autocorrect bubble on Safari. `type="search"` doesn't help either, nor does taking the input outside of the form.

```
    <input
      type="search"
      autocapitalize="off"
      autocorrect="off"
      spellcheck="false"
    />
```

[image]

Comment: Same, looks like a new issue since iOS 17